# table updation not happening

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is the code:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("update DateDeletion set DeletionDate= ? ,userName= ? where LedgerName='MiscelleniousExpenses'");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,Deletiondate);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,userName);
            //preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3,null);
            //preparedStatement.setString(4,"MiscelleniousExpenses");
            System.out.println("date :"+Deletiondate+"username :"+userName+"ts :"+timeStamp);
            int rowsUpdated= preparedStatement.executeUpdate();//for insert statement
            System.out.println(rowsUpdated);
            conn.close();
            if(rowsUpdated>0){
                System.out.println ("Ok."); 
                //ExpenditureMasterBeanInit();
                return "updated";
            }
```

rowsupdated is giving 0 rows updated.....when i check for 
'select Deletiondate from Datedeletion where LedgerName='MiscelleniousExpenses';
it is giving me one value what could be wrong??

Comment: Maybe the value in database is actually MiscellaniousExpenses, without the typo?

Comment: @JBNizet: or even MiscellaneousExpenses?  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/miscellaneous

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes indeed. I *knew* something looked strange :-)

Comment: guys it is like that in database itself.I have done the mistake there also :(.                                                   SQL> select LedgerName from datedeletion;

LEDGERNAME
------------------------------------------------

MiscelleniousExpenses                                                  any other solutions?

Comment: Can there be any oracle_sid based issue? because today i am trying to select. that is not happening either on that particular table which i created yesterday. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inserted records but did not commit. Thats why the data was not coming using JDBC in jsf page. How fool I have been.